# Transfer goods of a list

Tags: python, list, agent-based-modeling

```py
class Goods:
    def __init__(self, goods_list):
        self.goods_list = goods_list  # List of tuples (name, quantity)

    def transfer_goods(self, other_goods, good_index):
        """
        Transfer a random amount of goods from self to other_goods.
        """
        # Get the name and quantity of the goods to transfer
        good_name, self_quantity = self.goods_list[good_index]

        if self_quantity > 0:
            # Randomly select the amount to transfer
            amount = random.randint(1, self_quantity)

            print(
                f"Transferring {amount} {good_name} from Agent {self.unique_id} to Agent {other_goods.unique_id}")

            # Update quantities for the transferred goods
            self_goods_amount = self_quantity - amount
            other_goods_amount = other_goods.goods_list[good_index][1] + amount

            # Update the goods lists
            self.goods_list[good_index] = (good_name, self_goods_amount)
            other_goods.goods_list[good_index] = (good_name, other_goods_amount)

            print(f"After transfer:")
            print(f"Agent {self.unique_id}: {self.goods_list}")
            print(f"Agent {other_goods.unique_id}: {other_goods.goods_list}")
        else:
            print(f"Agent {self.unique_id} has no {good_name} to transfer.")
```

I am currently working on an ABM where the agents are supposed to exchange goods that are in list format ("name", quantity) but I cannot make the list update. All that happens is that the entry of the list is exchange with the entry of the other agent.

I would like the quantity updated if the type is the same and if not have the new entry added.

This all seems to be happening in the `transfer_goods()` method.

Comment: You have not explained exactly what happens when you run this code. What values are you passing in and what results do you get?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a list instead of a dictionary to track goods and amounts ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you notice the AttributeError exception when you ran your code?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to your problem.

I just had to modify a bit the types you used : I added an attribute `unique_id` to the class `Goods`. The rest remains unchanged. The function transfer_goods() transfers the goods from the first to the second list of goods.

You just need to make the following assumption : "All Goods have the same `good_names` in their `goods-list`, sorted in the same order". Otherwise it may be better to use dictionaries instead of tuple lists.

```
import random

class Goods:
    def __init__(self, unique_id, goods_list):
        self.unique_id = unique_id # Attribute added
        self.goods_list = goods_list  # List of tuples (name, quantity)

    def transfer_goods(self, other_goods, good_index):
        """
        Transfer a random amount of goods from self to other_goods.
        """
        # Get the name and quantity of the goods to transfer
        good_name, self_quantity = self.goods_list[good_index]

        if self_quantity > 0:
            # Randomly select the amount to transfer
            amount = random.randint(1, self_quantity)

            print(
            f"Transferring {amount} {good_name} from Agent {self.unique_id} to Agent {other_goods.unique_id}")

            # Update quantities for the transferred goods
            self_goods_amount = self_quantity - amount
            other_goods_amount = other_goods.goods_list[good_index][1] + amount

            # Update the goods lists
            self.goods_list[good_index] = (good_name, self_goods_amount)
            other_goods.goods_list[good_index] = (good_name, other_goods_amount)

            print(f"After transfer:")
            print(f"Agent {self.unique_id}: {self.goods_list}")
            print(f"Agent {other_goods.unique_id}: {other_goods.goods_list}")
        else:
            print(f"Agent {self.unique_id} has no {good_name} to transfer.")
```

For example, you can test it with the following goods :

```
initial_goods = Goods(0, [('patate', 3), ('tomate', 5), ('courgette', 1)])
other_goods = Goods(1, [('patate', 0), ('tomate', 0), ('courgette', 10)])

initial_goods.transfer_goods(other_goods, 0)
other_goods.goods_list
```

Comment: Another AI "solution"